# Countryside Stewardship Water Quality Priority Areas (England)

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, uk

I'm trying to acquire the 'Countryside Stewardship Water Quality Priority Areas (England)' which can be viewed [here](http://www.natureonthemap.naturalengland.org.uk/MagicMap.aspx) under `Countryside Stewardship Targeting & Scoring Layers`> `Water` (also shown below) in GIS format. I've tried calling the environment agency who Magic directs me to but the EA have no clue what this layer is.  I'm assuming there's no sneaky way to go into the development tools inside chrome and extract the layer out from the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The *sneaky* way of finding out more about the offering would be to use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), or some such tool and look what requests are made by your browser through the MAGIC client.

So you might see a request like:

http://www.natureonthemap.naturalengland.org.uk/proxy.ashx?http://gisdata.landmarkcloud.co.uk/arcgis/rest/services/MAGIC/Countryside/MapServer/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png8&bbox=321549.80964467005%2C607503.1725888324%2C421486.3578680203%2C693337.5634517766&bboxSR=27700&imageSR=27700&size=900%2C773&layers=show%3A64%2C65%2C66%2C67%2C68%2C69%2C70%2C71%2C72%2C73%2C74%2C75%2C76%2C77&f=image

Which if you open in a browser might look like:

[image: MAGIC countryside]

So you can see that there is a ArcGIS service behind the map and you might be able to extract vector data through the REST API

I see that the metadata says that data originator is the Environment Agency (EA), and I agree it is disappointing if you have contacted the EA and they don't know what data you mean!

**The less sneaky way**

I see too that the data distributor is Natural England through their  **Countryside Stewardship Development Team Subject Matter Expert (SMEX) – Data** contact.  I think the contact details you need are found on the following page:

https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/countryside-stewardship-get-paid-for-environmental-land-management